# Dynamically assigning properties on a non data bound ASP.NET control

Tags: asp.net

For example, let's say I have a HyperLink:

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" Text="Foo" NavigateUrl="foo.aspx" />
```

How can I set the NavigateUrl on the server side, without having to go the code-behind?

This doesn't work of course:

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" Text="Foo" NavigateUrl="<%= urlString %>" />
```

(where urlString might be a string I created earlier in the page)

And this doesn't work because the HyperLink is not within a data bound control:

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" Text="Foo" NavigateUrl='<%# urlString %>' />
```

I guess I could just use a standard anchor element:

```
<a href="<%= urlString %>">Foo</a>
```

But I'd rather not mix up HTML and ASP.NET controls, and it would be handy to be able to do this for other controls.

Surely there must be a way?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the property in an inline code block:

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="MyLink" Text="Foo"  />
<% MyLink.NavigateUrl="foo.aspx"; %>
```

Answer (score 1):

> This doesn't work of course:

Of course it does.

> And this doesn't work because the
>   HyperLink is not within a data bound
>   control:

Consider the Page as your data bound control.
You need to calls it's DataBind method.

```
Page.DataBind();
```

Maybe you need to add an ID attribute as well. If that does not work, try to display a property instead of a variable.

Comment: Actually the first example doesn't work. I just tested it again. It outputs "<%= urlString %>" as the href, all nicely HTML encoded.

Will try the Page.DataBind() option though, thanks.

Comment: Page.DataBind() works great, thanks. I wonder though, should I be concerned about efficiency here? Say you have a bunch of data bound controls on the page; GridViews, Repeaters and so on. If I call Page.DataBind() explicitly will ASP.NET end up binding those controls (and possibly calling the DB) twice?